# Regex: 3 ors and anything following "?"

Tags: regex

I'm trying to have only these 5 matches using:

`https://www.website\.com((\/compare)|(\/home-tips)|(?!(/[^?].)))`

1. https://www.website.com
2. https://www.website.com/compare
3. https://www.website.com/home-tips
4. https://www.website.com?anythinghere
5. https://www.website.com/?anythinghere

I can't seem to figure out why I still get a match with https://www.website.com/a or any other letter at the end (e.g https://www.website.com/b)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not matching the last 2 because you use a negative lookahead `(?!(/[^?].))` which does not consume any characters.

You could replace that witch matching an optional forward slash `/?`followed by matching a questionmark `\?` and match any character zero or more times `.*`.

To also match the first, make the whole outer group optional and you might omit the grouping of `(\/compare)` and `(\/home-tips)` if you are not using them for example in code or refer to them.

Your regex could look like:

[`^https://www.website\.com(?:/(?:compare|home-tips)|/?\?.*)?$`](https://regex101.com/r/hwfBnN/3)

That would match:

- `^https://www.website\.com` Match from the start of the string `https://www.website.com`
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `/` Match literally
  - `(?:`Non capturing group

    - `compare` Match literally
    - `|` Or
    - `home-tips` Match literally
  - `)` Close non capturing group
  - `|` Or
  - `/?\?.*` Match an optional forward slash, a questionmark followed by any character zero or more times
- `)?` Close non capturing group and make it optional
- `$` Assert the end of the string

Comment: Thanks. Does that not match any sub pages though? E.g. `https://www.website.com/test` should not match

Comment: @bhood I forgot the `$` to assert the end of the line. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put `^` at the start of your pattern and `$` at the end to anchor both ends of the expression to both ends of the string. Otherwise any partial match will return success (i.e. it is matching the `https://www.website.com` part of those strings).

Answer (score 0):

You dont have a match with current regexp, just be sure to escape it... see https://regexr.com/

I would however suggest to use something like `https:\/\/www.website\.com(?:\/(.*))?(?:\?.*)` and use switch on different paths to match, so that your regexp dont grow forever... This regexp gives you path and query.

---

Previous answer:

You can simply use non matching groups for that...

```
https:\/\/www.website\.com((?:\/compare)|(?:\/home-tips)|(?:\/?\?.+)?)
```